# ReactJS: How to use an immutable empty array or object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

In functional programming languages we often have a Nil / Empty object / array / list, as a singleton so that `Nil === Nil`.

In Javascript immutability is not by default so `[] !== []` and `{} !== {}`

The problem is that I'm getting payloads from a backend with sometimes empty arrays, or we sometime use empty arrays as default values too as it's convenient.

I'm using ReactJs in a pure way, with the equivalent of `PureRenderMixin` but sometimes we have components that do something similar to `<Comp myProp={[]}/>` (obviously simplified). And obviously that triggers unnecessary React renderings.

I guess I can do something like `<Comp myProp={MyCustomEmptyArraySingleton}/>` to solve the problem, or rework `PureRenderMixin`

What is the best way? So that the developpers do not have to think too much about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), which is developed by Facebook and it is meant to play well with React.

Comment: I know immutable but please tell me how you suggest me to use it to solve my problem. Indeed it seems Immutable JS have singletons as I can confirm `Immutable.List.of() === Immutable.List.of()`

Comment: I would implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, and use [is()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is) to check for changes.

Comment: That won't prevent developers to do things like `<Comp myProp={this.getImmutableJsArray() || []}/>`

Comment: I think that it is cumbersome to default the prop in that occasion. It is better to implement [getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops), which results in cleaner code. Be aware that mixins cannot be used in 0.13 ES6 syntax.

Comment: in my example, getImmutableJsArray is not necessarily a prop :)

Comment: It is a prop for `Comp`.